# Meta Titles appearing incorrectly on Google

Tags: seo, meta-tags, meta-description, technical-seo

I was hoping you could help me with a question about a Meta Title query as they seem to be appearing inaccurately - and its driving me mad.

Few considerations:

- Google seems to be displaying our old business name in SERPs (on some pages).
- Homepage displays old business name on Mobile, but new business name on Desktop (Chrome browser).
- We havent made any recent changes to Metas and the biz name was changes 2 years ago.
- It's not in the < title > tag or anywhere else in the page source (when you CTRL+F and search: "business name").

Is there a way of checking where it is pulling this string of text from? Could there be two conflicting references in the code that sets parameters globally?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no such thing as a "meta title" in HTML documents.   There are meta tags like "meta description" and "meta keywords" that are not visible on the page (only in the source code) but which search engines may use.   There is also the page title which is not a meta tag (it uses its own `<title>` tag) and is visible to users in browser tabs the browser title bar.  Are you asking about the page title or about the meta description here?

Comment: Thanks for your response. To clarify, I am referring to the < title> tag, which is visible on SERPs.